# LDAP Authentication failure for user

Tags: database, netezza, aginity

I installed a software called Coginiti Pro (Aginity Pro), entered the license key to activate the software, and tried to connect to the Netezza database/driver. But when the credentials are entered, I get an error message: LDAP Authentication failed:

How would we resolve this issue? I contacted coginiti pro support and they said that it was an error with the user credentials or wrong configuration with the database.

I tried to activate the license with a new license key, uninstall and reinstall software, and tried different variations of the username credentials.

Thank you,

[error message #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d8P6.png)
[error message #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg2b6.png)

Comment: Have you tried connecting to Netezza using nzsql or nzodbcsql from your remote system where Aginity is running?

Comment: No, I have not. The username and password used to login is used to login to the netezza database.

Comment: You need to login with your netezza user first - perhaps from the NZ host itself , then try nzsql from your workstation… if all that works - aginity (or excel or whatever) should Work as well… one step at the time

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what did you mean by the NZ host itself?